# EF Core 6 many-to-one relationship issues while seeding

Tags: c#, entity-relationship, seeding, ef-core-6.0

I'm porting a Spring framework (Java and Hibernate) based app to C# with EF Core, and it's proving to be quite a nightmare so far.

The current bump in the road is with a many-to-one relationship (not one to many...).

Object structure is the following, cutting out the property code for anything but the first to save on length:

```
public class Tax 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "binary(16)")]
    private Guid _id;

    public Guid Id 
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Label { /* same form as Id */}
    public String Code { /* same form as Id */}
    public Double Value { /* same form as Id */}
    // and more

    public static Tax[] Seed(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
            Tax tps = new Tax(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS", "G", 5, "123456789", Tax.TYPE_PERCENTAGE);
            Tax tvq = new Tax(Guid.NewGuid(), "TVQ", "Q", 9.975, "987654321TQ0001", Tax.TYPE_PERCENTAGE);

            Tax[] ac = new[]
            {
                tps,
                tvq
            };

            builder.Entity<Tax>(b =>
            {
                b.HasData(ac);
            });

            return ac;
        }
}

public class TaxGroup 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "binary(16)")]
    private Guid _id;
    public Guid Id 
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String Label { /* same form as Id */}
    public String Code { /* same form as Id */}

    private List<TaxGroupMember> _members;

    public virtual List<TaxGroupMember> Members 
    {
            get => _members;
            set
            {
                _members = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
    }
    // and more

   public static TaxGroup[] Seed(ModelBuilder builder, Tax[] ts )
   {
            var tps = ts.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "G");
            var tvq = ts.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "Q");

            TaxGroup gq = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS 5%, TVQ 9.975%", "GQ", "");
            
            TaxGroupMember gqm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tps);
            TaxGroupMember gqm2 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tvq);
            
            TaxGroup g = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS 5%", "G", "");
            TaxGroupMember gm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), g, tps);
            
            TaxGroup q = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TVQ 9.975%", "Q", "");
            TaxGroupMember qm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), q, tvq);
            
            TaxGroup[] tgs = new[]
            {
                gq,
                g,
                q
            };
            
            builder.Entity<TaxGroup>(b =>
            {
                b.HasData(tgs);
            });

            return tgs;
        }
}

public class TaxGroupMember 
{
    [Column(TypeName = "binary(16)")]
    private Guid _id;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Tax _tax;

    public virtual Tax Tax 
    {
            get => _tax;
            set
            {
                _tax = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
    }

    public virtual TaxGroup TaxGroup { /* same as Tax */}

    // and more

    public static void Seed(ModelBuilder builder, TaxGroup[] tgs, Tax[] ts)
    {
            var tps = ts.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "G");
            var tvq = ts.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "Q");
            
            var gq = tgs.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "GQ");
            var g = tgs.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "G");
            var q = tgs.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Code == "Q");
            
            TaxGroupMember gqm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tps);
            TaxGroupMember gqm2 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tvq);
            
            TaxGroupMember gm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), g, tps);
            
            TaxGroupMember qm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), q, tvq);
            
            TaxGroupMember[] tgms = new[]
            {
                gqm1,
                gqm2,
                gm1,
                qm1
            };
            
  
            builder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>(b =>
            {
                b.HasData(tgms);
            });
        }
}
```

In the `DataContext`, I have the following code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().HasIndex(e => e.TaxNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.Label).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.Code).HasMaxLength(5).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.TaxNumber).HasMaxLength(250).HasDefaultValue("");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().Property(e => e.TaxType).IsRequired();
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().HasIndex(e => e.Code);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().Property(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().Property(e => e.Label).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().Property(e => e.Code).HasMaxLength(5).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().Property(e => e.Notes).HasMaxLength(255);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroup>().Property(e => e.Taxes).IsRequired(false);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().Property(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().HasOne<TaxGroup>(p => p.TaxGroup);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().Navigation(e => e.TaxGroup).AutoInclude().UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property).HasField("_taxgroup");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().HasOne<Tax>(u => u.Tax);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaxGroupMember>().Navigation(e => e.Tax).AutoInclude().UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property).HasField("_tax");
        
        
        // SEED Tax, TaxGroup and TaxGroupMembers
        Tax[] taxes = Tax.Seed(modelBuilder);
        TaxGroup[] taxgroups = TaxGroup.Seed(modelBuilder, taxes);
        TaxGroupMember.Seed(modelBuilder,taxgroups, taxes);
```

I've tried just about every combination in the `DataContext` to allow the tables to be created properly (going from what I had in the Spring / Java app) and this generates the correct tables in the database.

The problem arises when I try to seed `TaxGroupMember`.

I've tried setting the `TaxGroup.Members` in the `TaxGroup.Seed()` by adding each obj before `HasData()`.

I've tried replacing `TaxGroup.Members` with `TaxGroup.Taxes (List<Tax>)` and populating the list from the `TaxGroup.Seed()` with no success either.

I'm getting various errors depending on the way I go about it.

What would be the proper way to set this relationship up in fluent EF Core 6 so that I can have various `TaxGroup`s which can have references to 0 or multiple `Tax` records.

It would undoubtedly be simpler to have a `Tax` record per group member but it would mean the end user would have to edit the tax values in each tax group rather than just the tax itself through a tax object editor dialog so I need to use this logic and find a way to model it in EF Core.

I could also use custom DB code to handle the concept but the app uses this concept a lot and to cut down on maintenance time and complexity, I'd much rather understand how to do it the proper way in EF Core.

**Edit #1:** After extensive testing, it seems to be an issue with EntityTypeBuilder<>.HasData() that doesn't understand that logic.

If I seed manually with the following code right after dbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync().Wait() and dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().Wait() it works fine. The tables are populated properly and DataContext.TaxGroups.ToList() as well as DataContext.TaxGroupMembers.ToList() return the proper objects including all referenced objects:

```
        public void SeedTaxes(DataContext dbContext)
        {
            Tax tps = new Tax(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS", "G", 5, "123456789", Tax.TYPE_PERCENTAGE);
            Tax tvq = new Tax(Guid.NewGuid(), "TVQ", "Q", 9.975, "987654321TQ0001", Tax.TYPE_PERCENTAGE);

            Tax[] ac = new[]
            {
                tps,
                tvq
            };

            dbContext.Taxes.AddRange(ac);


            TaxGroup gq = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS 5%, TVQ 9.975%", "GQ", "");

            TaxGroupMember gqm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tps);
            TaxGroupMember gqm2 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), gq, tvq);

            gq.Members.Add(gqm1);
            gq.Members.Add(gqm2);

            TaxGroup g = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TPS 5%", "G", "");
            TaxGroupMember gm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), g, tps);

            g.Members.Add(gm1);

            TaxGroup q = new TaxGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), "TVQ 9.975%", "Q", "");
            TaxGroupMember qm1 = new TaxGroupMember(Guid.NewGuid(), q, tvq);
            q.Members.Add(qm1);

            TaxGroup[] tgs = new[]
            {
                gq,
                g,
                q
            };

            dbContext.TaxGroups.AddRange(tgs);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: One thing that immediately stands out is that these Seed method are very awkwardly placed. In a Seed operation all primary an foreign keys should match, so it's usually better to do it in one monolithic operation where all dependent objects know their parents' PK values. I assume this is one of the sources of errors you get because you have `Guid.NewGuid()` "everywhere".

Comment: @GertArnold If I set breakpoints, the pk and fk are all set properly in each object but just to double check, I moved all the seed code directly into OnModelCreating() and it's still doing the same thing. If I read between the lines of the error, it's trying to seed another row of Tax with the same Guid PK for each TaxGroupMember

Comment: @GertArnold Here's the error it's giving with the edits: The seed entity for entity type 'TaxGroupMember' with the key value 'Id:e517da3b-021a-45a6-a8cf-bd08cc171344' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Tax' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'Tax' and specify the foreign key values {'Id'}.

Comment: You can't set navigation properties in seeding code.

Comment: @GertArnold Aside from stating the obvious, what's your suggestion to seed the TaxGroupMembers properly? I've already tried adding them directly into the TaxGroup seed code by populating the Members property which tells me to seed TaxGroupMember as the Members navigation is set.